# Is it safe to call memcpy with count greater than memory allocated for src?

Tags: c++, c

```c
std::string str = "hello world!";
char dest[16];
memcpy(dest, str.c_str(), 16);
```

str.c_str() will return a null-terminated char array. However, if I call memcpy with a count greater than 13, what would happen? Is dest going to be a null-terminated char array? Is there anything I need to be cautious about?

Comment: What's the matter with the _magic 13_ actually? Because it's _Friday the 13 of May_?

Comment: This is called a _buffer over-read_ (like a buffer overflow, only reading). Actually, the famous Heartbleed bug was caused by code like this.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "hello world!" with the null-termination is happen to be 13.

Comment: @DXM ^^^^ What a nice coincidence for a case asking about undefined behavior at a Friday 13th :-P ...

Comment: Would it be safe to do `str.c_str()[15]`, which is what memcpy is going to do for you?

Comment: @immibis The dest will be null terminated with some undefined data at the tail. Buf I don't really see how it's harmful. memcpy is not writing to str.c_str()[15]

Comment: @DXM Would it be safe to do `str.c_str()[100000000]`?

Comment: @DXM It's reading from it though. Reading from or writing to invalid addresses is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Kevin & immibis Point taken. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: 13 is good because you need to also copy the string terminator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you give it a count that's exactly how many sequential bytes will be copied. This means that all those bytes are read from after your string if you pass in a count larger than your actual source data. If this memory does not belong to your program to use, this might cause a crash due to a Segmentation Fault.

`strcpy` works differently in that sense since it checks for `'\0'`. Also if you want to copy bytes from a `std::string` to a `char[]`, you could simply not rely on dangerous C functions and use `std::copy`.

Answer (score 8):

Your code has undefined behaviour. When using `memcpy`, you need to make sure that the number of bytes being copied is not greater than the min(`size_of_recepient`, `size_of_source`).

In your case, the size of your source is 13 bytes, so copying more than that is not ok.

Answer (score 5):

> Is dest going to be a null-terminated char array? Is there anything I
>   need to be cautious about?

Unfortunately, the first parts of `dest` will be a null-terminated character array since `str.c_str()` returns a null terminated character array... But the remaining parts of `dest` will surely contain some additional garbage.

You are accessing additional memory that you have no idea about... *Your code could reformat your PC* ...its called Undefined behavior,

Comment: It doesn't matter whether there's additional garbage or not. What matters is that you're accessing memory beyond the end of the object. If you were copying from a sufficiently large object containing a null-terminated character array followed by garbage, there would be no problem; `memcpy` would just harmlessly copy the garbage.

Answer (score 3):

It's not safe. You should use `strncpy`, which was made for this.  What's after the end of the `"hello world!"` `std::string` is undefined. It could be an undefined part of your heap, in which case you'll be copying what might be called garbage, or it could be venturing into an unallocated memory page, in which case you'll get a segfault and your program dies. (Unless it has some clever magic to handle segfaults, which, judging by your question, it probably does not have.)